# Python list slice [0:-1:-1]

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I ran into this statement while I was coding:

```
l = [1,2,3]
print(l[0:-1:-1])
```

I was expecting this piece of code gives me `[1]` however it gives me `[]`, makes me think I must have mis-understood python slice operation, can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

In a slice,

The first integer is the index where the slice starts.

The second integer is the index where the slice ends.

The third integer specifies a stride or step causing the resulting slice to skip items. -1 for reverse the output.

```
l[0:-1:-1]
```

is equivalent to

```
l[len(l)-1:len(l)-1:-1]
```

The first index converted `0` to `len(l)-1`, because you added `-1` in the last index to reverse the list. This will always give you an empty list.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still not sure I understood. specifically what's the logic behind converting 0 to len(l)-1?

Comment: When you reverse list then last index become  first. For example, actual list index [0, 1, 2, 3]. After you reverse it will [3, 2, 1, 0].

Answer (score 0):

When you use slice in python and you type

```
l[x:y:-1]
```

it would somehow be equivalent to

```
l.reverse()
print(l[y:x])
l.reverse()
```

but with the difference that -1 reverses the list **elements with their indexes**
so if you type

```
l=[1, 2, 3]
l[2:0:-1]
```

the output will be

```
[3, 2]
```

The reason for empty list is that you change the order of indexes so it wont find any element in that window...

Comment: Hi, so I'm thinking about l[0:-1:-1] will be equivalent to l.reverse() then l[-1:0] right? in that case I guess my question becomes why [-1:0] will give an empty string... I look at this and expecting [-1:0] will give me the last element of a list...

Comment: Actually it's not completely like reverse... as I said the difference between these two is that reverse makes a whole new list with each element having new indexes and the indexes will be in right order but using -1 as third input of slice will reverse the indexes or should I say each element in a list will keep it's own index when you use -1 because you just change the way you look at the same list. You are not making a new list... but when you use reverse each element have a new index because it constructs a new list and saves it so it would have proper indexing

Answer (score 0):

I gathered some information after talking with friends about this problem, now we kind of believe this is what happened: when I do l[0:-1:-1], the first thing interpreter will do is to convert that second -1 to the positive index, which is 2 in my case. Then it will iterate backward with the terminating condition being "start <= end", in this case since at the very beginning it will find 0 <= 2, so it will directly terminate, results in the output array being empty.
I didn't really get what the two other answers are saying here (silly me), maybe they are right, I need to look into the python source code for a 100% certain explanation, but for now I believe what I just stated here is the case.